# d3-geomap Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: d3.js, geospatial

I'm trying to use d3-geomap to visualize regions that have been recently established to administer the delivery of children's mental health services in Ontario, Canada. I've converted a publicly available shapefile of the these administrative regions to a topojson format file and I've aligned estimates of numbers of 0 - 18 years olds across these regions for 2014 - 2041.
My webpage at 
http://cartoserve.com/maps/ontario/cymhsas_population/cymhsas_pop_2014.html is meant to display the estimated population for 2014, but throws the following error: "topojson.js:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined". I hate to admit how much time I've spent figuring out this problem! Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading components in following order

1. d3.geomap.dependencies.min.js
2. d3.geomap.min.js